# <div> that only scrolls horizontally?

Tags: html, css, scroll

How can I create a  element that only scrolls horizontally?  If it makes sense, I want the element to act like it is position:fixed when the user scrolls vertically down the page, but act like it's position:static for sideways scrolling.

HTML/CSS solutions preferred, but if it isnt' feasible, JavaScript fixes are fine.

Answer (score 1):

```
<div style="width:400px;height:400px;overflow:auto;">
    <div style="width:800px;">
        bunch o text  
    </div>
</div>
```

You mean something like this?

Comment: is there any other way where we don't need to set width and as we add child elements the parent width expands?